# Hammock suspension system: Could Case Logic's suspension system harm the camera?

Tags: nikon, equipment-protection, camera-cases

I've recently purchased a Case Logic camera backpack and it comes with a built-in a suspension system that seems quite nice at the first glance. Here I have attached its photo.

[image]

Although this sounds nice, I noticed that when I leave the camera there, the suspension rubber exerts some pressure on the function key of my Nikon D7200. I'm not sure if the continuous pressure it cause can damage the function key or it will be all right.

To clarify more, the suspension system is an elastic rubber that holds the camera still in the case.

Comment: Wow, that seems thoroughly unnecessary.  It's a camera, not an egg.

Comment: @Blrfl: The advantage is that, it is a backpack, and you may sometime be running with that on your shoulders, so the camera does not move. I feels more comfortable but there came the question.

Comment: @Transcendent: if you expect to run you should have a tightly-packed bag held well against you're body. In other words, the camera should be packed tight in the bag anyway. I'm with Blrfl, this suspension idea sounds wholly unnecessary.

Comment: @DanWolfgang: It's actually the Case Logic's idea not mine :D. Anyways, the question is something else.

Answer (score 2):

The `Fn` button on the front of your D7200 is *meant* to be depressed. The only downside to having it depressed while in storage would be if it were to cause the camera to power on, which I doubt is the case but I do not have a D7200 to confirm.

Further, the D7200 has primarily a magnesium alloy body and is literally meant to take a bit of abuse even including light rain. I wouldn't spend much time concerning yourself with use related problems as it is built to withstand all but the most rugged environments.

Comment: There's no doubt that that button is meant to be pressed, but it will be a persistent press for many hours especially when I'm flying to somewhere. So do you think it'd be all right?

Comment: If it's meant to be pressed multiple times, one would *expect* that it should be fine being pressed once, for a long time.